# Why the fire is blue when there is enough oxygen?

Tags: visible-light

In the kitchen the flame is blue when there is enough oxygen. Is it true that the amount of oxygen has effect in fire color, why blue, why yellow sometimes?

Answer (score 7):

Yellow flames are due to glowing particles of soot that emit a black-body spectrum. These will only form when there is not enough oxygen in the gas mixture (incomplete combustion).

The blue emission comes from excited molecules that are produced in the chemical reactions.

Comment: ...and if you strike the burner assembly with a kitchen tool, the flame will suddenly glow orange because the dirt particles knocked into the flame are rich in sodium.

Answer (score 0):

There are many factors that determine the color of fire.

**What is burning** The light released by the fire is due to exogeneous chemical oxidation reactions, and therefore depends on the type of the material that is burning. Kitchen stoves use methane gas, which is rather different from the long organic chains in wood.

**The temperature**  The temperature of fire depends on the type of material burning, the shape of the furnace/candle/etc., the convection conditions, availability of oxygen, etc.

See, e.g., [here](https://sciencing.com/colors-fire-hot-8631323.html).

Comment: The question was about a kitchen stove, so probably methane.

Comment: @Pieter Yes, this is what I wrote. Also, kitchen stoves are rather optimized for efficiency, so it is unlikely that they suffer from the lack of oxygen.

Comment: @Pieter, Methane, if the gas is supplied to your home through a network of underground pipes. Propane, if you live in a rural area, where your cooking "gas" is periodically delivered by a tanker truck and stored on your property. Prior to World War II, [town gas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coal_gas)—a by-product of manufacturing coke for the steel industry—was a mixture of various hydrocarbons, along with hydrogen and carbon monoxide. The CO content was high enough that inhaling gas directly from the kitchen oven was a well-known means of suicide.

Comment: @Vadim  if the wrong orifice size is used (natural gas vs. propane, for example), the mixture will be suboptimal and you'll get a large yellow-orange flame rather than the desired blue.